# Getting ESLint to ignore unused Angular $log variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, atom-editor, eslint

For JavaScript I'm using ESLint in Atom with Angular 1.5. I have the following excerpt in my `.eslintrc` file:

```
"rules": {
    "no-unused-vars": ["warn", {
        "varsIgnorePattern": "\\$log"
    }]
```

The [ESLint `no-unused-vars` documentation](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars) says I can use a regular expression. Yet ESLint still gives me a warning for the `$log` variable I have injected in an Angular controller. (I've tried `"$log"` as well with no escaping, and the same thing happens.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [**args**IgnorePattern](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars#argsignorepattern) instead of **vars**signorepattern

Comment: Woohoo!! OK, I get it --- I hadn't understood the distinction between unused _variables_ and unused function _arguments_. I had a little mental blocks when reading the docs. Changing that to `"argsIgnorePattern": "\\$log"` did the trick! (For the record, `"log"` does _not_ work; the `$` has to be escaped, I suppose because this is a regular expression.) Thanks so much for the quick and accurate response!